# Geometric median of two disjoint sets of points lies on line between their respective medians

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, linear-algebra, divide-and-conquer

I was working on a problem about geometric medians and I had an idea for a divide and conquer solution, but it would only work if a set of points, when split into two disjoint sets, and those sets respective geometric medians calculated and a line passed between, it holds that the geometric median of the overall set of points lies on that line. When graphing it and visualizing it, seems possible, and when I used existing algorithms and experimented, it seems to be **very close** but not quite on the same line. I am not sure if this is due to error in calculation of the geometric median or not.

I have some example Python code demonstrating how close the numbers are here: [Geometric Median comparison](https://tio.run/##zVRNj5swEL37V0y3FzsLBAepSlFXqtQ99biKtCuhaOUFJ7EKhhqzLf3z6dgkIdntflU9lEOCZ94bvzce0/R2U@skbPqm327fQzgJIa8LpdcpdHYVzl2EnJ2dkS9GCisLqDUsNh187TTAB@BxGidpEsMs5h8J@Sw6rGdSkMl8PovnnklU1dTGgu6qpgfRgm7IytQVtLlq@qhthFWijArVWqFzCTt47gIByC4vVSGFJqSQK1jLupLWqPy2koUSmt4gpGkvuAz5jKUE8OnhAveIKjmkY0Z8@MdGlRIWppMDzD2XCPUbOWDWL9kho2v9S5q6RQC9hHcXWCZLsdiSjGSl7zHNYQqX2R6/PEm3g5S2q6hbjuWvMeH50wF3SCxGxjVM4GYsPDrx@rrqdi@wlGiUQbgn7injdmp1TEAzYwt8xzhWWRxCsnyIH3Y4JRlpO6OhP6K18hRy5bq3QGE9Qy@nRn2JwWyptCjXka5NRa/YKWLocewcGK/cbzOqm5rHTirxk8YB8NCx2WQB51ApTXkAQ6Anx405TBjtA@Qz@OQm6s9e@SHqhgyXw1T6CRIB3O1atINXwm6i9ruxlIosXoZ3@MMmkxnqwQB3Ae4DeK4E@2CELuoqaqUsaMKIla29FcaI3UD7V5plI3L4o2zC4zg4EXz8/BH/Gnin1cqdSRLNArzhMVsCrkGB0oMeodeS4t4uFbhQUXd3pWTOzD1e5/wbpaOL4AUTIU@eVvWsnTczHzh7tTG2u4GkwUmy1J/7o0/S6Dhz92Zcsul0li5ZAM9QGNs7ebF4nD4u/@@q/410OP8/tD9R/c12998itt3@Bg)

Any expertise in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are two set of points, the geometric median of $A \cup B$ does **not** necessarily lie on the line passing between the geometric mean of A and the geometric mean of $B$.

In the following example the points of $A$ are red and the one in $B$ is blue. The geometric median of $A$ is the red square. The green line connects the geometric means of $A$ and $B$. The black square is the geometric mean of $A \cup B$, i.e., the [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) of the triangle whose vertices are in $A \cup B$.

[image: Geometric mean]

Comment: Oh wow...how did I miss such an obvious case. Thank you!

Comment: Doing some more testing and it looks like the more points you have the closer it falls to the line. Never quite on it though